# Memoization of dynamic programming problem. Why does the following solution not work?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search, memoization

I am attempting the following problem on Leetcode: [Best time to buy and sell stock II](https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-ii/)

Basically, my approach is:

```
    [7,1,5,3,6,4]
      /        \
    Buy         Not Buy
 (profit=-7)     (profit=0)
 /       \ 
 Sell      Not Sell 
profit=-6     profit=-7
```

I am attempting a depth first search approach using a stack to explore the state space. Each entry in stack is a tuple containing the following:

- current profit
- whether we are in a position to buy or not
- index in the input array
- instruction which is either 'ENTER' or 'EXIT'. Enter means we are entering the node in the tree. On the way up, the entry will be 'EXIT' when we pop from stack, and that is when we know it is time to get max of children nodes.

So far I have implemented the solution, and it works.

My solution without memoization is as follows and it passes test cases:

```
def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:

    # Stack tuple order -> profit, buying, index , stack_instruction
    stack = [(0, True, 0, 'ENTER')]
    d = dict()
    while stack:
        profit, buying, index, ins = stack.pop()
        if index >= len(prices):
            d[(index, buying)] = profit
            
        elif ins == 'ENTER':
            stack.append((profit, buying, index, 'EXIT'))
            
            if buying:  # Can buy
                stack.append((profit - prices[index], not buying, index+1,'ENTER'))
                    
            else: # Can sell
                stack.append((profit + prices[index], not buying, index+1, 'ENTER'))
                    
            # Skip / take no action
            stack.append((profit, buying, index+1, 'ENTER'))
        else:
            # on the way up post order traversal
            d[(index,  buying)] = max(d.get((index+1, not buying)), d.get((index+1,  buying)))
    print(d)
    return d.get((0, True))
```

Basically I have been using an explicit stack which mimics recursion. The recursive equivalent should be as follows:

```
    def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
    dp = {}
    
    def dfs(i: int = 0, buying: bool = True) -> int:
        if i >= len(prices):
            return 0

        if (i, buying) in dp:
            return dp[(i, buying)]
        
        cooldown_profit = dfs(i + 1, buying)
        
        if buying:
            buying_profit = dfs(i + 1, not buying) - prices[i]
            dp[(i, buying)] = max(cooldown_profit, buying_profit)
         
        else:
            selling_profit = dfs(i + 1, not buying) + prices[i]
            dp[(i, buying)] = max(cooldown_profit, selling_profit)
        
        return dp[(i, buying)]
        
    return dfs()
```

However when I attempt to implement memoization using the following code additions (marked as **
**), it fails to give the correct solution. Can someone please point out where I am going wrong?

```
    def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:

    # Stack tuple order -> profit, buying, index , stack_instruction
    stack = [(0, True, 0, 'ENTER')]
    d = dict()
    while stack:
        profit, buying, index, ins = stack.pop()
        if index >= len(prices):
            d[(index, buying)] = profit
            
        elif ins == 'ENTER':
            stack.append((profit, buying, index, 'EXIT'))
            
            if buying:  # Can buy
                **if (index+1, not buying) not in d:**
                    stack.append((profit - prices[index], not buying, index+1,'ENTER'))
                    
            else: # Can sell
                **if (index+1, not buying) not in d:**
                    stack.append((profit + prices[index], not buying, index+1, 'ENTER'))
                    
            # Skip / take no action
            **if (index+1, buying) not in d:**
                stack.append((profit, buying, index+1, 'ENTER'))
        else:
            # on the way up post order traversal
            d[(index,  buying)] = max(d.get((index+1, not buying)), d.get((index+1,  buying)))
            
            
    print(d)
    return d.get((0, True))
```

Comment: General-purpose memoization is provided by the standard library: it is called `functools.lru_cache`.

Comment: I know, however, I want to implement it using dictionary to truly understand the concept. Would you be able to advise where I am going wrong in my attempt?

Comment: This problem is solved in O(n) time and O(1) space without using stack. You basically need to find sums of the `max-min` of all non-decreasing subarrays of `prices`. Can you please explain your approach in details? What are you searching for and what are you using stack for?

Comment: I am basically attempting depth first search to explore end states that are possible. My solution works, however, when I attempt to use memoization using dictionary to cache states, it fails to give the correct output.. I want to understand why my memoization attempt is failing. I know there are better solutions, however, I would like to understand why my approach specifically is not working

Comment: I understand that. What I'm trying to say, your solution is not at all obvious, compared to [a single-loop approach](https://gist.github.com/Aivean/00e485a38948263c2dc1ae6a5a4d7994).   If you want your question to be answered, please edit it to include more details on your approach, including what stack holds in each moment of time. Tracing it for a simple input will also help.

Comment: It seems that you try to make a simple problem harder than necessary... @Aivean  has good suggestion for you.

Comment: @Aivean I have added some description, including a tree visualization describing my approach.

Comment: Thank you. As far as I can tell, you've rewritten recursion using explicit stack + state machine (which doesn't help with understanding). Can you provide the recursive form or just the recurrent (dynamic) function you're trying to solve for the reference?

Comment: @Aivean Thanks so much for having a look at the code. Yes, correct. My attempt uses an explicit stack to mimic recursion in an iterative manner. I have added recursive equivalent of the code in the edit.

Comment: Your recursive variant is not equivalent to your explicit stack variant. In recursive variant you're not using `profit` from lower indices, while in the stack variant you do. I'd suggest to add extensive logging to both approaches, including the full stack state in each step to ensure they are actually equivalent. To be frank, I doubt  that you'll find people here to do that tedious debugging for you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get memoization working in my code. Hence I am answering my own question. Essentially, my base case was wrong.

```
class Solution:
def maxProfit(self, prices) -> int:
    # index, buying, ins
    stack = [(0, True, 1)]
    d = dict()
    #calls = 0
    while stack:
        index, buying, ins = stack.pop()
        #calls +=1
        if index >= len(prices):
            d[(index, buying)] = 0
        elif ins == 1:
            stack.append((index, buying,  0))
            if (index + 1, not buying) not in d:
                stack.append((index + 1, not buying,1))
            if (index + 1,buying) not in d:
                stack.append((index + 1,  buying,1))
        else:
            lst = []
            if buying:
                lst.append(d.get((index+1, not buying)) - prices[index])
            else:
                lst.append(d.get((index+1, not buying)) + prices[index])
            
            lst.append(d.get((index+1, buying)))
            
            d[(index, buying)] = max(lst)
            
    #print(d)
    #print(calls)
    return d.get((0, True))
```